# Remove the rows that does not have incident data

Tags: sql-server, select, duplicates, sql-server-2014

I have incident data as shown in this image:

[image: this image].

I want to write a query based on these conditions:

1. If for a particular month there is an incident data based on county, site and month then the empty incident row should be removed as shown by red colored "X"
2. If there is no incident data based on county, site and date then the empty row should be preserved, as shown by green colored tick

I can't use functions or stored procedures.

Comment: *"as shown in the image"* What image? However, before you *do* post that image, don't. Post the data as **formatted** `text`. Images of data aren't helpful to the volunteers you're asking for help from.

Comment: @Larnu I edited the post so at least people could link to it in the meantime (I intentionally kept it as a link instead of putting it in the post).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "removed"? Do you mean removed from the query results, or deleted from the table altogether?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes. It should not appear when I run the sql query.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Your question is very likely easy to answer. However, you haven't provided any details so nobody actually know what the question is. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for ideas on how to turn this into a question that others can help you with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a list of all unique combinations of `County`, `Site`, 'Site Number`, and`Date`(month), and then you want`Incident`and`Priority`, if they exist.

It's a two step question. First, generate your list of unique values. That's the inner sub-query with the `GROUP BY`.

Then do a `LEFT JOIN` back to the base table, but only where an `Incident` exists. That's the last of the `JOIN` criteria in the `ON` clause.

The result set will show only `Incident` data where it exists (getting rid of the empty records you want gone), but will create an empty record for each unique combination that doesn't have any incidents. The `COALESCE` statements are just window dressing to make the results pretty.

Data Setup:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
  (
    County   VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
   ,Site     VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
   ,SiteName VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
   ,Date     VARCHAR(6)  NOT NULL
   ,Incident VARCHAR(5)  NULL
   ,Priority CHAR(2)     NULL
  );
INSERT @t
  (
    County
   ,Site
   ,SiteName
   ,Date
   ,Incident
   ,Priority
  )
VALUES
  ('C1', 'S1', 'Sn1', 'Jan-19', 'INC3', '')
 ,('C1', 'S1', 'Sn1', 'Jan-19', '', '')
 ,('C1', 'S1', 'Sn1', 'Feb-19', 'INC2', '')
 ,('C1', 'S1', 'Sn1', 'Feb-19', 'INC1', '')
 ,('C1', 'S1', 'Sn1', 'Feb-19', '', '')
 ,('C1', 'S2', 'Sn2', 'Jan-19', '', '')
 ,('C1', 'S2', 'Sn2', 'Feb-19', '', '');
```

Query:

```
SELECT
  list.County
 ,list.Site
 ,list.SiteName
 ,list.Date
 ,COALESCE(t1.Incident, '') AS Incident
 ,COALESCE(t1.Priority, '') AS Priority
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      t.County
     ,t.Site
     ,t.SiteName
     ,t.Date
    FROM
      @t AS t
    GROUP BY
      t.County
     ,t.Site
     ,t.SiteName
     ,t.Date
  ) AS list
LEFT JOIN
  @t AS t1
    ON
    t1.County = list.County
      AND t1.Site = list.Site
      AND t1.SiteName = list.SiteName
      AND t1.Date = list.Date
      AND t1.Incident <> '';
```

Results:

```
+--------+------+----------+--------+----------+----------+
| County | Site | SiteName |  Date  | Incident | Priority |
+--------+------+----------+--------+----------+----------+
| C1     | S1   | Sn1      | Feb-19 | INC2     |          |
| C1     | S1   | Sn1      | Feb-19 | INC1     |          |
| C1     | S1   | Sn1      | Jan-19 | INC3     |          |
| C1     | S2   | Sn2      | Feb-19 |          |          |
| C1     | S2   | Sn2      | Jan-19 |          |          |
+--------+------+----------+--------+----------+----------+
```